# Support both 540px and 500px in tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying to make my tumblr theme support both 500px and 540px posts in their original size (without resorting to either upscaling og downscaling a picture). I found and followed a guide that made this possible, but the problem is that photosets consisting of photos larger than 268px no longer appear side by side, but above each other.

Most photosets are already arranged with 2 pictures side by side in one row or 3 pictures in one row, some even have 1 picture in each row - is it possible to keep the original arrangement? My problem is mainly with 2x photosets, and 3x photosets that were too large and were thus arranged one by one above each other in high res - is it possible to do something about that? Is it possible to make these big pictures in photosets smaller and to make them appear side by side?

The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

<meta name="color:Background Color" content="#edebe9" />
<meta name="image:Background" content=""/>
<meta name="color:Post Background" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:Header Title Color" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:Main Color" content="#7b7978" />
<meta name="color:Accent" content="#ffbabf">

<meta name="image:Header" content="" />
<meta name="image:Sidebar" content="" />

<meta name="text:Header Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 1 Title" content="refresh" />
<meta name="text:Link 1 Url" content="/" />
<meta name="text:Link 2 Title" content="message" />
<meta name="text:Link 2 Url" content="/ask" />
<meta name="text:Link 3 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 3 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 4 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 4 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 5 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 5 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 6 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 6 Url" content="" />

<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 1 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 1 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 2 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 2 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 3 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 3 Url" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 4 Title" content="" />
<meta name="text:Sidebar Link 4 Url" content="" />

<meta name="if:Shows Sidebar Links" content="1" />


<title>{Title}</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
{block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}" />{/block:Description}

<!-- tooltips -->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/rzl30kg/eAxm7a751/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>
<script>
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[title]").style_my_tooltips({
tip_follows_cursor:true,
tip_delay_time:200,
tip_fade_speed:300
}
);
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

<!-- font -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Montserrat:400,700:latin', 'Open+Sans:400,300,600,700:latin' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>


<style type="text/css">

/*-- Font--*/

@font-face {
font-family:icons;
src:url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/sag7r4mkfdw7jcn/theme51.ttf');
}

/*-- Basic --*/

html, body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background-color:{color:Background Color};
background-image:url('http://oi64.tinypic.com/rkylaf.jpg');
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:0px;
margin-top:0px;
overflow-x:hidden;
background-attachment:fixed;
}

}

a{
color:{color:Accent};
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover, a:active{
color:{color:Main Color};
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#s-m-t-tooltip{
position:absolute;
max-width:150px;
z-index:999999999999;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:10px;
display:block;
padding:5px 8px;
background:{color:Main Color};
font-size:8px;
color:{color:Background Color};
letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
width:9px;
border:2px solid {color:Background Color};
background-color:{color:Accent};
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
width:9px;
border:4px solid {color:Background Color};
background-color:{color:Accent};
}

::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
color:#fff;
background-color:{color:Accent};
}

::selection {
color:#fff;
background-color:{color:Accent};
}

figure{
margin-top:10px;
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}

/*-- Tumblr Controls --*/

.tmblr-iframe.tmblr-iframe--desktop-logged-in-controls.iframe-controls--desktop{
white-space:nowrap;
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
-moz-filter: invert(100%);
-o-filter: invert(100%);
-ms-filter: invert(100%);
filter: invert(100%);
opacity:0.2;
}





/*-- Header --*/

/*-- Topbar --*/

.header{
left:calc(50% - 360px);
width:730px;
top:0px;
position:absolute;
}

.sticky {
position:fixed;
top:0px;
z-index:9999;
height:40px;
}

#topbar{
text-align:center;
background-color:{color:Post Background};
box-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
}

#topbar a{
display:inline-block;
font-size:8px;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
letter-spacing:2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
height:37px;
line-height:40px;
color:{color:Main Color};
padding:0px 8px 0px 10px;
margin:0px 5px;
border-bottom:3px solid transparent;
}

#topbar a:hover{
border-bottom:3px solid {color:Accent};
color:{color:Accent};
}


/*-- Sidebar --*/

#sidebar{
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:50px;
width:150px;
text-align:left;
overflow:hidden;
background:{color:Post Background};
box-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
border-radius:3px;
}

#sidebarimg img{
width:150px;
}

#desc{
font-weight:400;
text-align:justify;
width:110px;
padding:15px 20px;
line-height:150%;
font-size:9px;
color:{color:Main Color};
letter-spacing:0.5px;
}

#navi{
border-top:1px solid {color:Background Color};
}

#navi a{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
display:block;
width:110px;
padding:15px 20px;
text-align:left;
color:{color:Main Color};
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:7.5px;
letter-spacing:2px;
line-height:100%;
border-bottom:1px solid {color:Background Color};
}

#navi a:last-child{
border:none;
}

a.link1::before{
content: "\e900";
}

a.link2::before{
content: "\e901";
}

a.link3::before{
content: "\e902";
}

a.link4::before{
content: "\e903";
}

a.link1::before,
a.link2::before,
a.link3::before,
a.link4::before{
font-family:'icons';
font-size:12px;
float:left;
margin-right:10px;
color:{color:Accent};
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a.link1:hover::before,
a.link2:hover::before,
a.link3:hover::before,
a.link4:hover::before{
color:#fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#navi a:hover{
color:#fff;
background-color:{color:Accent};
}


#pagination{
border-top:1px solid {color:Background Color};
width:110px;
padding:0px 20px;
text-align:center;
font-size:9px;
}

#pagination a{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 5px 8px 5px;
width:5px;
font-size:8px;
color:{color:Main Color};
border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
}

#pagination a:hover{
border-bottom:2px solid {color:Accent};
}

.current_page{
color:{color:Main Color};
display:inline-block;
padding:10px 5px 8px 5px;
width:5px;
font-size:8px;
border-bottom:2px solid {color:Accent};
}

#pagination a.jump{
font-family:Helvetica;
font-size:9px;
}


/*-- Posts --*/

#posts{
position:absolute;
top:30px;
left:calc(50% - 191px);
width:540px;
padding-bottom:50px;
}

#post{
font-weight:400;
font-size:9.5px;
width:550px;
padding:6px;
background-color:{color:Post Background};
color:{color:Main Color};
text-align:justify;
line-height:150%;
margin-top:30px;
letter-spacing:0.5px;
overflow:hidden;
box-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
border-radius:3px;
}



/* BASIC */

#post img{
max-width:100%;
padding: 1.5px 1.5px 1.5px 1.5px;
}

#post a{
color:{color:Accent};
}

#post a:hover{
color:{color:Main Color};
}

.posttitle{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:0px;
width:540px;
text-align:justify;
margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
color:{color:Main Color};
}

blockquote{
width:calc(100% - 23px);
max-width:calc(100% - 23px);
margin-left:10px;
padding-left:10px;
border-left:2px solid {color:Accent};
}

p{
margin-top:3px;
}

ol {
margin-left:-15px;
}

ul {
list-style-type:disc;
margin-left:-15px;
}


/* LINKS */

.link-button {
background:#f2f2f2;
word-break:break-word;
overflow:hidden;
display:block;
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
margin-bottom:10px;
}

.info-container {
padding:20px 20px 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.publisher-container{
margin-top:-4px;
margin-bottom:17px;
display:block;
font-size:13px;
line-height:16px;
font-weight:700;
word-break:break-all;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:20px;
right:20px;
}

.publisher-container .publisher{
line-height:16px;
font-size:8px;
font-weight:500;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
text-transform:uppercase;
letter-spacing:2px;
display:inline-block;
margin:0px;
}

.publisher-container .publisher:before{
font-size:14px;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
font-family:'icons';
content:'\e908';
}

.info-container{
padding:20px 20px 0;
overflow:hidden;
}

.info-container .title{
margin-top:-5px;
margin-bottom:14px;
display:block;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:0px;
line-height:130%;
color:{color:Accent};
}

.info-container .title:after{
padding-left:5px;
white-space:nowrap;
display:inline;
vertical-align:middle;
font-family:'icons';
content: "\e907";
}

.info-container .excerpt {
margin-top:-5px;
margin-bottom:14px;
display:block;
font-size:10px;
line-height:130%;
color:{color:Main Color};
}

/* QUOTES */

.quotes{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:0px;
letter-spacing:0px;
width:540px;
line-height:130%;
color:{color:Main Color};
}

.quotes:before{
font-family:'icons';
content:'\e905';
margin-right:8px;
}

.quotes:after{
font-family:'icons';
content:'\e906';
margin-left:8px;
}

/* ASKS */

.asker{
font-size:7px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:left;
line-height:100%;
color:{color:Main Color};
letter-spacing:2px;
}

.asker span{
color:{color:Main Color};
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:lowercase;
font-size:12px;
line-height:130%;
letter-spacing:0px;
}

.asker a{
color:{color:Main Color};
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight:400;
text-transform:lowercase;
font-size:12px;
line-height:130%;
letter-spacing:0px;
}

.asker a:hover{
color:{color:Accent};
}

.askimg img{
width:25px;
height:25px;
margin-right:10px;
border-radius:50%;
float:left;
}

.question{
width:470px;
margin-left:12px;
margin-bottom:10px;
padding:20px 0px 10px 20px;
border-left:1px solid {color:Accent};
margin-top:-5px;
}

/* CHAT */

ul.chat, .chat ol, .chat li .chat li{
list-style:none;
line-height:180%;
margin-left:-35px;
}

/* POST NOTES */

#postnotes{
width:540px;
padding:20px;
color:{color:Main Color};
background:{color:Post Background};
font-size:8px;
text-align:justify;
line-height:150%;
margin-top:20px;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-transform:uppercase;
box-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
border-radius:3px;
}

ol.notes {
padding:0px;
margin:25px 0px;
list-style-type:none;
border-bottom:solid 1px {color:Background Color};
}

ol.notes li.note {
border-top:solid 1px {color:Background Color};
padding:10px;
}

ol.notes li.note img.avatar {
vertical-align:-4px;
margin-right:10px;
width:16px;
height:16px;
border-radius:50%;
}


/*-- Permalink --*/

#permalink{
width:540px;
text-align:left;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:8px;
line-height:100%;
border-bottom:solid 1px {color:Background Color};
color:{color:Post Background};
padding:0px 10px 13px 20px;
margin-top:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
margin-left:-15px;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

#permalink a{
font-weight:300 !important;
color:{color:Main Color};
margin:0px 5px;
}

#permalink a:first-child{
margin-left:0px;
}

#permalink a:hover{
color:{color:Accent};
}

#permalink a.notes{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size:10px;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

.like_and_reblog_buttons{
list-style:none;
margin-top:-13px;
}

.like_and_reblog_buttons li{
float:right;
margin:0px;
margin-left:10px;
height:20px;
cursor:pointer !important;
}

#tags{
width:540px;
text-align:right;
line-height:100%;
border-top:solid 1px {color:Background Color};
color:{color:Post Background};
padding:10px 10px 0px 10px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:-20px;
letter-spacing:0.5px;
line-height:150%;
font-weight:400 !important;
font-size:8px;
}

#tags a{
display:inline-block;
color:{color:Main Color};
margin-left:10px;
opacity:0.5;
}

#tags a:hover{
color:{color:Accent};
opacity:1;
}

#tags a:before {
font-family:'icons';
font-size:7px;
content: "\e904";
margin-right:5px;
float:left;
}




/*------» do noт reмove «------*/

#credit {
font-family:Helvetica;
font-weight:300;
font-size:12px;
position:fixed;
bottom:10px;
right:10px;
z-index:99999;
}

#credit a{
display:block;
color:#fff;
background:{color:Accent};
padding:5px;
line-height:97%;
height:10px;
width:10px;
overflow:hidden !important;
text-align:center;
}

#credit a:hover{
padding-right:90px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#thememaker{
margin-left:15px;
margin-top:-11px;
font-size:7px;
letter-spacing:3px;
}

/*------» тнαик уσυ «------*/



</style>

</head>

<body>


<!-- [[•------» do noт reмove «------•]] -->

<div id="credit">
<a href="http://roxiestheme.com" target:"_blank">©<div id="thememaker">ROXIESTHEME</div></a>
</div>

<!-- [[•------»   тнαик уσυ   «------•]] -->

<div id="header">
<div class="title"><h1>{text:Header Title}</h1></div>
</div>

<div class="header">

<div id="topbar">
{block:IfLink1Title}<a href="{text:Link 1 Url}">{text:Link 1 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink1Title}
{block:IfLink2Title}<a href="{text:Link 2 Url}">{text:Link 2 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink2Title}
{block:IfLink3Title}<a href="{text:Link 3 Url}">{text:Link 3 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink3Title}
{block:IfLink4Title}<a href="{text:Link 4 Url}">{text:Link 4 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink4Title}
{block:IfLink5Title}<a href="{text:Link 5 Url}">{text:Link 5 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink5Title}
{block:IfLink6Title}<a href="{text:Link 6 Url}">{text:Link 6 Title}</a>{/block:Iflink6Title}
</div><!-- topbar -->

<div id="sidebar">

<div id="sidebarimg"><img src="{image:Sidebar}"></div>

<div id="desc">{description}</div>

{block:IfShowsSidebarLinks}
<div id="navi">
{block:IfSidebarLink1Title}<a href="{text:Sidebar Link 1 Url}" class="link1">{text:Sidebar Link 1 Title}</a>{/block:IfSidebarLink1Title}
{block:IfSidebarLink2Title}<a href="{text:Sidebar Link 2 Url}" class="link2">{text:Sidebar Link 2 Title}</a>{/block:IfSidebarLink2Title}
{block:IfSidebarLink3Title}<a href="{text:Sidebar Link 3 Url}" class="link3">{text:Sidebar Link 3 Title}</a>{/block:IfSidebarLink3Title}
{block:IfSidebarLink4Title}<a href="{text:Sidebar Link 4 Url}" class="link4">{text:Sidebar Link 4 Title}</a>{/block:IfSidebarLink4Title}
</div>
{/block:IfShowsSidebarLinks}

{block:Pagination}
<div id="pagination">
{block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}" class="jump">←</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
{block:JumpPagination length="3"}{block:CurrentPage}
<span class="current_page">{PageNumber}</span>
{/block:CurrentPage}{block:JumpPage}
<a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
{/block:JumpPage}{/block:JumpPagination}
{block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}" class="jump">→</a>{/block:NextPage}
</div>
{/block:Pagination}

</div><!-- sidebar -->

</div><!-- class=header-->

<script>
var header = document.querySelector('.header');
var origOffsetY = header.offsetTop;

function onScroll(e) {
  window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? header.classList.add('sticky') :
                                  header.classList.remove('sticky');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
</script>

<div id="posts">

{block:Posts}

<div id="post">

{block:Date}
<div id="permalink">
{block:NoteCount}
<a class="notes" href="{Permalink}">{NoteCount}</a>
{/block:NoteCount}
<a href="/day/{Year}/{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonthWithZero}/">{ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero} {Year}</a>
{block:RebloggedFrom}<a href="{ReblogParentURL}" target="_blank" title="{ReblogParentName}">via</a>/<a href="{ReblogRootURL}" target="_blank" title="{ReblogRootName}">src</a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}
<ul class="like_and_reblog_buttons">
<li>{LikeButton size="13"}</li>
<li>{ReblogButton size="13"}</li>
</ul>
</div>
{/block:Date}


{block:Text}
{block:Title}<div class="posttitle">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
{Body}
{/block:Text}

{block:Link}
<a href="{Url}" target="_blank" class="link-button">
{block:Thumbnail}<div class="thumbnail" style="width:540px;height:auto;background-image:url('{Thumbnail}');"></div>{/block:Thumbnail}
<div class="info-container">
{block:Host}<div class="publisher-container"><div class="publisher">{Host}</div></div>{/block:Host}
<div class="title">{Name}</div>
{block:Excerpt} <div class="excerpt">{Excerpt}</div>{/block:Excerpt}
</div></a>
{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}

{block:Photo}
{LinkOpenTag}
<center><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"></center>
{LinkCloseTag}
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}
{block:ReblogParentURL}
<!-- {block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ReblogParentURL}
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
<center>{block:Photos} <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"max-width="540px"> {/block:Photos}</center>
{block:Caption}<div id="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
<div class="quotes">{Quote}</div>
{block:Source}<br>
<div style="font-size:9px;">— {Source}</div>
{/block:Source}
<br>
{/block:Quote}

{block:Chat}
{block:Title}
<div class="posttitle">
{Title}
</div>
{/block:Title}
<ul class="chat">
{block:Lines}
<li class="user_{UserNumber}">
{block:Label}
<span class="label" style="color:{color:Color One}"><b>{Label}</b></span>
{/block:Label}
&nbsp;{Line}
</li>
{/block:Lines}
</ul>
{/block:Chat}

{block:Audio}
{AudioEmbed-500}
{block:caption}{Caption}{/block:caption}
{/block:Audio}

{block:Video}
<center>{Video-500}</center>
{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
{/block:Video}

{block:Answer}
<div class="askimg"><img src="{AskerPortraitURL-48}"></div>
<div class="asker">
<span>{Asker}</span>
<br>sent a message
</div>
<div class="question">{Question}</div>
{Answer}{/block:Answer}

{block:HasTags}
<div id="tags">
{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
</div>
{/block:HasTags}


</div><!-- post -->

{block:PostNotes}
<div id="postnotes">
{PostNotes}
</div>
{/block:PostNotes}

{/block:Posts}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  /* questions? ask oddhour.tumblr.com */
     var updatePhotosetCss = "<style id='updatePhotosetStyle'> .photoset .photoset_row.photoset_row_1 img { max-width: 540px; } .photoset .photoset_row.photoset_row_2 img { max-width: 268px; } .photoset .photoset_row.photoset_row_3 img { max-width: 177px; } .photoset .photoset_row { text-align: center; width: 540px; } .photoset { width: 540px; }</style>";
   function updatePhotoset() {

        $(".photoset").each( function (i, e) {
            if($(this.contentDocument).find("#updatePhotosetStyle").size() <= 0) 
                $(this.contentDocument).find("head").append(updatePhotosetCss);
            var photoset = $(this.contentDocument).find(".photoset");
            var photosetRows = photoset.find(".photoset_row");  
            photoset.find(".photoset_photo")
                .each(function () {
                    var hiResSrc = $(this).attr("href");
                    var img = $(this).find('img');
                    img.attr("src", hiResSrc );
                    img.attr("style", "");
                });
            photosetRows.attr("style", "").css("margin-bottom", "-5px");
            photoset.attr("style","");

            $(this).height($(this.contentDocument.body).height());
        });
    }

    updatePhotoset();

    var photosetTimer = setInterval(updatePhotoset, 1500);
    $(window).on('load', function () { setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(photosetTimer)}, 2000); })
</script>

</div><!-- posts -->

</body>





</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write the **CSS** too in the question. Please write the css of **#post** and **.postcontent**

Comment: I added the entire code. It seems there's no .postcontent

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it says that **#posts** has a width of **540px**. which contains **#post**. and also your **#post** has a width of **550px**. So, if you want to arrange 2 or 3 posts in a row, you have to increase the width of #posts and decrease the width of #post. 
The concept is so simple. If **#posts** has a width of 100% and **#post** has a width of 50%, then it will show 2 posts in a row.
Suppose you want 2 posts in a row. then...

```css
#posts{
width:540px;  /*in your code it is 540px*/
}
#post{
width:250px;  /*in your code it is 550px, change it to 250px*/
display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want a theme like [**this**](http://funny-adults.com) you can contact me.  Also send the link of your blog here in the comment.